# python how to print complete math calculation steps in a list(set)

Tags: python-3.x

I am a new programmer. I have a little program that calculates from a list of numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] all the numbers that add up to 10 and prints them in a new list as strings: eg 1+9=10, 9+1=10

How can i write a code that prevents the same calculation from being added to my new list(set(name of list)) every time it is computed.
I used to get the same strings added to my list so i eliminated the duplicates by converting the list to a set but then i have the problem that 1+9=10 and 9+1=10 is not recognised by the program.
How can i get around this?
Thanks very much

Comment: After the program calculates a combination = 10 it converts to a string and i put htat string in the 'set'....but the set also includes calculations that are similar but obviously it does not recognise that...i  hope it is clear..its quite a big program so i did not put it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python, but I would place the biggest number in front of the string/calculation so the strings match.

Sorry if this code is not Python-like, but I think you'll get the thing.

```
...
int a;
int b;
string c;

if(a+b == 10)
{
     if(a>b)
     {
         c = a + "+" + b + "=10";
     }
     else
     {
         c = b + "+" + a + "=10"
     }
}
...
```

Then add `string c` to your list like you used to, checking for duplicates.
I hope this is the answer for you!

Comment: oh i see , so i should order them before they go into the list...cools